# Error using strptime, strftime while converting date to epoch

Tags: ruby, datetime

I am trying to extract dates from csv file and convert them to epoch time

```
CSV.foreach(File.path("month.csv")) do |row|
 dateper=row[0].split(',')[0] 
 p DateTime.strptime(dateper,"%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p %z").strftime("%s")
end
```

I am getting *invalid date (ArgumentError)* as the result. However, if I print out dateper, choose one of the outputs randomly and cop-paste it in place of dateper in line 3, I get an epoch value. What am I doing wrong? dateper is of string value, and strptime minus strftime seems to give an output.

month.csv sample:

7/26/13 12:00:00 AM -05:00,62.2,63.02,62.07,63.02,5.00168E+07
8/23/13 12:00:00 AM -05:00,71.84,71.93,71.36,71.6,5.55304E+07
8/26/13 12:00:00 AM -05:00,71.56,72.91,71.52,71.87,8.26536E+07
8/27/13 12:00:00 AM -05:00,71.16,71.81,69.49,69.82,1.058488E+08

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Could you give a couple lines from your CSV? Ideally, the lines that you find don't work?

Comment: Put  `puts dateper` after your `dateper = ...` declaration to see if it matches what you think it's supposed to be.

Comment: @Amadan:
 One row of CSV has
 7/26/13 12:00:00 AM -05:00,62.2,63.02,62.07,63.02,5.00168E+07

More row would look like
8/23/13 12:00:00 AM -05:00,71.84,71.93,71.36,71.6,5.55304E+07
8/26/13 12:00:00 AM -05:00,71.56,72.91,71.52,71.87,8.26536E+07
8/27/13 12:00:00 AM -05:00,71.16,71.81,69.49,69.82,1.058488E+08

Comment: @Beartech p dateper gave me "7/13/15 12:00:00 AM -05:00" as one of the many dates

Comment: If it gave you that as one of the *many dates*, that means your code worked for many rows. What was the last row that it printed before the error? I would suppose that you have a badly formatted date in it.

Comment: I saved the data you posted to a .csv file and ran your code in pry. Worked perfect. My first suspect would be a problem with your .csv file. What OS are you on? Is your .csv file a pure text file? Do you know what line-ending characters are in use? i.e. Windows or Unix?

Comment: Amadan brings up a good point you need to clarify. Do you get the error immediately or do some lines process successfully?

Comment: OK, I put a space before one of my lines and the script choked on that line with the exact same error. So Amadan is probably right, you have a malformed date somewhere.

Comment: Thanks so much guys! Turns out of the dates was flawed. It is working well now. Truly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have some malformed dates somewhere. Use `rescue` to avoid the script choking on them.

```
CSV.foreach(File.path("month.csv")) do |row|
 dateper=row[0].split(',')[0] 
 p DateTime.strptime(dateper,"%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p %z").strftime("%s") rescue p "malformed date:#{dateper} on line #{$.}"
end
```

This will allow the script to continue and show you the bad dates.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that was helpful :)